# 301 moved permanently how to fix?

Tags: wordpress, http

When I am trying share my website link on Facebook then this message comes up 
"301 Moved Permanently". I don't know what is happened with my website . If any one knows how to fix this issue please let me know .
My website is built on Wordpress.

TIA

Comment: You probably shared the incorrect link that's getting redirected. You should share the final redirected link. Post the link you're trying to share on Facebook.

Comment: Hi Josep Thank you for your reply . Here is the screenshot https://prnt.sc/n70gs4   what actually happens when I share the link on facebook